# Attribute error in PIL object

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm using Debian Linux with Python 2.7. I get an raise `AttributeError` message

```
AttributeError: __setitem__
```

for the lines

```
lena[mask] = 0
lena[range(400), range(400)] = 255
```

What am I doing wrong.

```
from PIL import Image
import scipy
from scipy import ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from scipy import misc
import scipy.misc
import copy


lena = Image.open("/home/pi/Desktop/testc.jpg")
array = lena.convert('L')
array=np.asarray(array)
arr=copy.deepcopy(array)
arr[10:13, 20:23]
arr[100:120] = 255

lx, ly = lena.size
X, Y = np.ogrid[0:lx, 0:ly]
mask = (X - lx/2)**2 + (Y - ly/2)**2 > lx*ly/4
lena[mask] = 0
lena[range(400), range(400)] = 255
```

Comment: Did you mean to assign to `arr[mask]` instead perhaps? `lena` is your image object, and doesn't support item assignment.

Comment: I think @Martijn has the right answer below, but I just wanted to note: don't slice with `range`, use slice notation: `arr[:400,:400] = 255`.  Each time you call `range`, a new list that you'll never use again is created.

Answer (score 2):

PIL image objects do not support item assignment; `lena` is your PIL `Image` object.

Did you mean to assign to the numpy `array` instead? If so, use:

```
arr[mask] = 0
arr[:400, :400] = 255
```

where I replaced the `range(400)` objects with slice notation (much more efficient).